# Web-app or Google document editors add-on/ for creating Google Forms quizzes with an specific number of random questions

Tags: web-apps, educational, google-apps

## Tl;Dr

I'm looking for a recommendation for a tool to create Google Forms quizzes with a specific number of randomly selected questions from a question bank.

## User story

I'm a teacher that use Google Forms quizzes to evaluate student learning progress on weekly, bi-monthly and period basis but also I should rate the questions according their difficulty based on the students performance on that questions.

Let say that I have

- a question bank with `A` number of questions
- a `B` number of students
- the students are distributed across `C` number of sessions / groups

My goal is to my students respond Google Forms quizzes with a random selection of `D` number of questions.

A, B, C, D numbers will vary due to different reasons

Let say that now I want to create a quiz with 7 questions from a question bank with 73 questions that should be responded by 117 students where the group of 8 am has 17 students, the group of 10 am has 24, the group of 12 pm has 44 and the group of 4pm has 21 and the group of the 6 pm has 28. The next week, I will create another quiz with 13 questions from the same question bank for the same students.

Once the students responded the quiz I should prepare a report telling me how many students responded each question, the individual score for that question by quiz, the min, max, average, std scores by session / group and the whole student population by quiz and historically. If the tool makes this report this will be a big plus.

My students and I have G Suite for Education accounts and Google common accounts so it doesn't matter if the recommend software require one type of Google account or the other.

I don't always use Google Classroom / Google Sites but if the web-app / add-on require them it I'm open to use any of them, but it will be a plus if the tool include a way to send an email to each student with the link to the Google Form quiz that they should respond.

I'm open to use an add-on for any of the Google document editor web apps and to use an stand-alone web app.

If the tool is a paid tool it should include a free tier or trial.